# Delete file from C:\Windows folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working with an application that was poorly designed. When installed, it creates a .INI file (remember those?) in the C:\Windows folder. In order to get things working correctly in our environment, I don't use that .INI file. Instead, I have separate .INI files in a different location where I can properly management them within the framework of the application. The problem I'm running in to is users not running the application correctly so it picks up this default .INI file that doesn't work in our environment (remember I said the application is poorly designed).

To make sure that my users are running the correct configuration, I need to delete this pesky .INI from the C:\Windows folder. I have .BAT files that manage application launch and updates so I tried to just issue a delete in the .BAT file but it isn't working. When I try to run just the delete command in a command window, I get "Access Denied". I can't rename it or move it either. I would just go touch each computer but don't have the time to get to them all.

I have just spent the last two hours googling to find a solution and the only solutions are to use Windows Explorer which isn't an option. I know it has to be something simple that I haven't been able to find. Ideas?

Comment: Are you running the command prompt or batch script as an Administrator?

Comment: An administrator would just delete from their computer `del "\\computername\C$\windows\file.ini`

Comment: Have you been successful deleting the file using "Windows Explorer?"

Comment: Considering it installs a file to the Windows folder, the install would have had to run with elevated privileges which means your batch file needs to run with elevated priviliges.

Comment: SomethingDark, I have not tried running the batch script as an administrator. While I have that privilege, most folks do not so I have to get it to work otherwise. My users are the ones kicking off the batch file which does the updates.

Comment: CatCat, while I have rights to do what you are suggesting, the average user does not. Although, as I think about it, I might just prepare a script to do this since we only have four sub-nets. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: lit, I haven't tried through Windows Explorer since my users don't have enough knowledge (or desire) to do it that way.

Comment: Squashman, you're correct that their installer is what creates the file. Any chance you know how to provide elevated privileges in a batch file NOT run as an administrator?

Comment: The average user cannot delete files in C:\windows. Ever. This is by design.

Comment: Files added to C:\Windows that are not part of the OS should be deleteable by the average user. I get why and I know that's a Microsoft decision but...

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in ("%userprofile%\Desktop\ComputerName.txt") do echo Del \\%A\C$\Windows\file.ini
```

Computername.txt is one computer per line, names or addresses.

```
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but I'm getting access denied on a number of machines. Oh well, it was a good effort.